# Javascript Sub Categories - Clearing Selections

Tags: javascript

This is an additional question regarding sub categories. The current problem is that when I change options the function to clear the OS list is not working and it conntinues to grow as changes are made.  I tried adding the remove function everywhere and it still does not work.  To recreate the issue, select internal for network and then look at the OS list.  Select physical for resource and then look at the OS list.  I have a function called removeAllOptions in the list.js file that is not clearing the OS selections when the resource is changed.  It does work when the network is changed. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ray

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ey8E/1/)

**index.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
    <script language="javascript" src="list.js"></script>
    </head>
    <head>
   <script language="javascript" src="list.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="left_box" />
<body onload="fillCategory();">
   <div id="formWrapper" />
   <FORM name="drop_list" action="availability.php" method="POST" />
   <fieldset>
      <label>Network</label>
      <SELECT class="formSelect" NAME="build" onChange="selectResource();">
         <Option value="">Select Internal or Firewall</option>
      </SELECT>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>Resource</label>
      <SELECT class="formSelect" id="resource" NAME="resource" 
          onChange="selectOS(this);">
         <Option value="">Resource</option>
      </SELECT>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>OS</label>
      <SELECT class="formSelect" id="OS" NAME="OS">
         <Option value="">OS</option>
      </SELECT>
      <br />
      <br />
   </fieldset>
```

**list.js**

```
function fillCategory(){ 
 // this function is used to fill the category list on load
addOption(document.drop_list.build, "Internal", "Internal", "");
addOption(document.drop_list.build, "Internal Cluster", "Internal Cluster", "");
addOption(document.drop_list.build, "Firewall", "Firewall", "");
addOption(document.drop_list.build, "Firewall Cluster", "Firewall Cluster", "");
}

function selectResource(){
// ON selection of category this function will work
removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.resource);
removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.OS);

if((document.drop_list.build.value == 'Internal')||(document.drop_list.build.value == 'Firewall')){
addOption(document.drop_list.resource,"Virtual", "Virtual","");
addOption(document.drop_list.resource,"Physical", "Physical","");
}

if((document.drop_list.build.value == 'Internal Cluster') || (document.drop_list.build.value     == 'Firewall Cluster')) {
addOption(document.drop_list.resource,"Physical", "Physical");
}
    selectOS();
}
function selectOS(el){

if(document.drop_list.build.value == 'Internal') {
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"AIX 6.1", "AIX 6.1");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 5.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 5.0 (64-bit)");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 6.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 6.0 (64-bit)");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Solaris 10", "Solaris 10");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Standard", "Windows 2008 (64-bit) Standard");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 (64-bit)   Enterprise");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Standard", "Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit)  Standard");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Special", "Special");
}

if((document.drop_list.build.value == 'Internal Cluster') ||(document.drop_list.build.value == 'Firewall Cluster')){
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"AIX 6.1", "AIX 6.1");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 5.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 5.0 (64-bit)");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 6.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 6.0 (64-bit)");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Solaris 10", "Solaris 10");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise");
}

if((document.drop_list.build.value == 'Firewall') && (document.drop_list.resource.value == 'Virtual')) {
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 5.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 5.0 (64-bit)");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 6.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 6.0 (64-bit)");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise");
}

if((document.drop_list.build.value == 'Firewall') && (document.drop_list.resource.value == 'Physical')) {
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"AIX 6.1", "AIX 6.1");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 5.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 5.0 (64-bit)");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 6.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 6.0 (64-bit)");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Solaris 10", "Solaris 10");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise");
addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise");
}

} 

function removeAllOptions(selectbox)
{
    var i;
    for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    //selectbox.options.remove(i);
    selectbox.remove(i);
}
} 


function addOption(selectbox, value, text )
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = text;
optn.value = value;

selectbox.options.add(optn);
}
```

Comment: You have too much of repeated code.. Also try avoiding javascript code in inline HTML

Comment: Any reason for not using jQuery or similar library? They create an abstraction over the quirks of various browsers and give us a standard behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Quick fix you can call the `removeAllOptions()` function whenever you call the function.

But you have too much of repeated code , and trying to access a **DOM** every single time you call the select box.

**Better to cache them.**

**Code**

```
var networkList = '';
var resourceList = '';
var osList = '';

function fillCategory() {
    // this function is used to fill the category list on load
    networkList = document.drop_list.build;
    resourceList = document.drop_list.resource;
    osList = document.drop_list.OS;
    var catOptions = ["Internal", "Internal Cluster"
                      , "Firewall", "Firewall Cluster"];
    addOptions(networkList, catOptions);
}

function selectResource() {
    // ON selection of category this function will work
    removeAllOptions(resourceList);
    removeAllOptions(osList);
    var networkValue = networkList.value;

    if ((networkValue == 'Internal') || (networkValue == 'Firewall')) {
        addOptions(resourceList, ["Virtual", "Physical"]);
    }
    else if ((networkValue == 'Internal Cluster') 
               || (networkValue == 'Firewall Cluster')) {
        addOptions(resourceList, ["Physical"]);
    }
    selectOS();
}

function selectOS(el) {
    var networkValue = networkList.value;
    var resourceValue = resourceList.value;

    var internalOS = ["AIX 6.1","Linux 5.0 (64-bit)","Linux 6.0 (64-bit)"
                      ,"Solaris 10","Windows 2008 (64-bit) Standard"
                      ,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise"
                      , "Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Standard" 
                      ,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise"
                      , "Special"];
    var clusterOS = ["AIX 6.1","Linux 5.0 (64-bit)","Linux 6.0 (64-bit)",
                     "Solaris 10","Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise"
                     ,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise" ];

    var firewallOS = ["Linux 5.0 (64-bit)","Linux 6.0 (64-bit)"
                       ,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise"
                      ,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise" ];

    removeAllOptions(osList); // Clear your OS list here
    if (networkValue == 'Internal') {
        addOptions(osList , internalOS);
    }
    else if ((networkValue == 'Internal Cluster') 
              || (networkValue == 'Firewall Cluster')) {
        addOptions(osList , clusterOS);
    }
    else if ((networkValue == 'Firewall') && (resourceValue == 'Virtual')) {
       addOptions(osList , firewallOS);
    }
    else if ((networkValue == 'Firewall') && (resourceValue == 'Physical')) {
        addOptions(osList , clusterOS);
    }

}

function removeAllOptions(selectbox) {
    var i;
    for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}

function addOptions(selectbox, arr) {
    // use an array to populate Select Options
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
        optn.text = arr[i];
        optn.value = arr[i];
        selectbox.options.add(optn);
    }
}​
```

This can be **lot more optimized..**  Also you can use jQuery for such purposes. Better to move the inline javascript to the script itself.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7ey8E/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

The code to clear the select options, ie `removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.OS);` is called from the function `selectResource`. However, your `resource` `onChange` handler is directly calling `selectOS`, completely bypassing the options removal code.

The solution:

```
function selectResource(){
    // ON selection of category this function will work
    removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.resource);

    if((document.drop_list.build.value == 'Internal')||(document.drop_list.build.value == 'Firewall')) {
        addOption(document.drop_list.resource,"Virtual", "Virtual","");
        addOption(document.drop_list.resource,"Physical", "Physical","");
    }

    if((document.drop_list.build.value == 'Internal Cluster') || (document.drop_list.build.value     == 'Firewall Cluster')) {
        addOption(document.drop_list.resource,"Physical", "Physical");
    }

    selectOS();
}

function selectOS(el) {

    removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.OS);

    if(document.drop_list.build.value == 'Internal') {
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"AIX 6.1", "AIX 6.1");
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 5.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 5.0 (64-bit)");
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Linux 6.0 (64-bit)", "Linux 6.0 (64-bit)");
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Solaris 10", "Solaris 10");
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Standard", "Windows 2008 (64-bit) Standard");
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 (64-bit)   Enterprise");
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Standard", "Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit)  Standard");
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise", "Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) Enterprise");
        addOption(document.drop_list.OS,"Special", "Special");
    }

    // the remaing code of this function

}
```

The change I made was to move the `removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.OS);` to inside `selectOS`.

**Suggestion:** Please use a dom library like jQuery. I noticed you are using `.value` to retrieve the selected value of the select box. There are reported cases of the code not working on certain versions of IE. Similarly, there are other quirks in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you all for the great help.